# Updating camel version in fuse esb

Tags: apache-camel, fuseesb

Hi I would like to know  which camel version is used in Fuse esb (jboss-fuse-6.0.0.redhat-024),

according to the migration guide it's 2.10.0 .

how can I update it to use 2.10.5 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JBoss fuse is using customer version of Camel which is based on the Camel 2.10.x branch.
As there are lots other projects which may relates to this Camel version, I don't suggest you to change the version yourself.