# Jboss Fuse 6.1.0 upgrade camel feature version

Tags: apache-camel, jbossfuse

I have been working with Jboss Fuse 6.1.0.redhat-379 for about a month with great results and higher productivity in EIP. Thank you very much to the community for building such a great product.

Now I am getting ready to deploy my bundles in a dev enviroment with several camel routes and even multiple camel contexts in a single bundle and I'm noticing a weird behavior regarding camel contexts JMX display. The bundle with the multiple camel contexts is only showing the first context, others contexts work fine but they are missing in camel JMX display in hawtio.

After research about this behavior I encountered with this JIRA issue https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-7545 opened by Claus, describing exactly this problem and manifesting that there are Fix Versions (2.12.4, 2.13.2, 2.14.0)

AFAIK my Jboss Fuse version is distributed with camel 2.12.0.redhat-610379 version and there is a mayor 2.14.0.redhat-620031 version that supposedly will fix this issue and it will be bring many other features like json path and sql generated keys.

Is there a way to upgrade versions of camel features in Jboss Fuse?

## UPDATE

There is a similar question for this topic ([Updating camel version in fuse esb](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17806786/3521068)) accepted answer discourages trying to update the version, however, I think it should be better to permit version upgrades if they fix issues

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a 100% on this but the rollup patches might include the 2.12 fixed versions. Install the latest patch and see if that fixes the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @carbon. How can I install the lastest patch? is it only by changing dependency pom version?

Comment: Patches for JBoss Fuse can be downloaded using the Red Hat customer portal.

Comment: Hello Claus! I will login into Red Hat customer portal and check it out. Thanks a lot

Comment: I logged in with my Red Hat account and activated the 90 day subscription  Self- Supported Jboss fuse. There is a whole chapter in the documentation regarding to how to apply patches. jboss-fuse-6.1.0.redhat-379-r2p1-611424-1 seems to resolve the issue. Thank you again