# How to upgrade the camel version in jboss fuse 6.0

Tags: jboss, apache-camel, apache-karaf, fuseesb, jbossfuse

How can we upgrade the version of camel along with all the available camel compenents like camel-jetty,camel-jms etc avaialble in jboss Fuse?

list command shows the version as 'camel-jetty (2.10.0.redhat-60065)' . I need to pick up fix for a camel-jetty issue mentioned here.[Camel-jetty bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-5821)

Can features:install karaf command be used for this purpose. It was mentioned in a response that manual upgrade of features in Fuse should be avoided ( *[Updating camel version in fuse esb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17806786/updating-camel-version-in-fuse-esb)* )

Any pointers on this would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a subscription to use JBoss Fuse in production.

You should use the Red Hat customer portal to get issues resolved in JBoss Fuse. They will be able to provide a patch with the fix that you can then install on your JBoss Fuse installation.

Also the customer portal has a list of existing patches you can download, and it could be that the jetty bug has already been fixed in one of those.

Comment: Can you please provide the link for the available patches?

Comment: They are in the customer portal which you need to login